# Do I need Microsoft.Bcl.Async package in .NET 4.5?

Tags: .net, .net-4.0, async-await, .net-4.5

I have a project `P` which is targeting .NET Framework 4.5 and it has a NuGet package `A` which is targeted for 4.0 (it has no 4.5). Now, `A` has a dependency to `Microsoft.Bcl.Async` NuGet package. Is it safe to force-remove the dependency to `Microsoft.Bcl.Async` for the project `P` since it is targeting 4.5? If it is indeed safe to remove it - why?

Comment: https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/12/dont-be-afraid-to-use-the-science/

Comment: First you should contact the author of that package. This package should be updated so as to work properly. Second, if that author does not respond, that probably shows the death of the package and you should check on NuGet.org a better alternative.

Comment: @LexLi What's wrong with making a package that supports older version of .Net? Other than that, I don't see any indication in the question that the package does not work properly.

Comment: @svick the author should at least create separate dependency list for net40 and net45, to avoid .NET 4.5 users being bothered by `Microsoft.Bcl.Async`. If you check other famous packages you can see they do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You still need Microsoft.Bcl.Async. The assemblies from package A are going to reference types and methods from assemblies in the Microsoft.Bcl.Async package. And while on .Net 4.5, you have methods with *equivalent functionality*, you won't have *exactly the same* methods, so package A won't work.

For example, if you `await` a `Task` on .Net while using Microsoft.Bcl.Async, your code will call the extension method `public static TaskAwaiter GetAwaiter(this Task task)` on the `AwaitExtensions` type in the `Microsoft.Threading.Tasks` assembly.

On .Net 4.5 that assembly does not exist, so such code wouldn't work.

Comment: I took @Hans Passant advice and dug up a bit more after simulating what @svick already explained very well. I looked at the IL of the `async` methods. They have the `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncStateMachineAttribute` from the `System.Runtime` assembly which comes from the `Microsoft.Bcl` NuGet package.